# Was unexpected at this time. Error level correcting and continue

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to have my batch file go to a spot if something was unexpected at this time instead of killing the program. This is what I have so far.

```
:StartConvo


if %errorlevel% neq 0 (goto skiperror & /b %errorlevel%>>ErrorLog.txt) else (goto skiperror)

:skiperror

set InVar=


set /p InVar=%Encrypt%:%=%

If /I "%InVar%"=="/c" goto Commands 
If /I "%InVar%"=="/cls" goto CryptoClear
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Releave" goto Kick
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Test" goto Test
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Tuna" goto Tuna
If /I "%InVar%"=="/SProfile" goto Usrchk
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Login" goto Login
If /I "%InVar%"=="/USRC" goto USRC
If /I "%InVar%"=="/msg" goto msg
If /I "%InVar%"=="/photo" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Pic" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Pics" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Photos" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Pictures" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/Picture" goto photo
If /I "%InVar%"=="/log" goto log
If /I "%InVar%"=="/sticker" goto sticker
If /I "%InVar%"=="/expandedstorage" goto expandedstorage
If /I "%InVar%"=="/es" goto expandedstorage
If /I "%InVar%"=="/History" goto History
If /I "%InVar%"=="/CL" goto Changelog
find /c "%Encrypt%" kick.txt >NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto Kicked


find /c "%Encrypt%" T.txt >NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto Tunaed

@echo #%Encrypt%:%InVar%>> msg.txt


find /c ":" %Encrypt%.usr >NUL

if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto privtxt

GOTO StartConvo
```

If someone types << || && it breaks the program how do I fix this?

Comment: `%Encrypt%:%=%` you you really have a variable named `%=%`? And escaping in cmd is a pain in the _ so it's better to avoid that and use powershell instead

Comment: @phuclv: You can't define a variable containing a `=` in batch (but you can use it for some reason). So sometimes `%=%` (or some variation like `%= this is a comment =%` is used as a "guaranteed empty variable". I see it used quite often with `set /p`, mainly to make trailing spaces visible (`set /p var=prompt: %=%`), but I see no advantage to `set /p "var=prompt: "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs, when you use the string without quotes (quotes make poison chars like `&<>|` safe). That happens with your `@echo` line.

Replace

```
@echo #%Encrypt%:%InVar%>> msg.txt
```

with

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("#%Encrypt%:%InVar%") do >>msg.txt @echo %%a
```

(Note: can still break when there are quotes in the input string)

Comment: That fixes it and I don't even need the error aversion! Though in this code I had to change the @echo to just echo.

Comment: Just to make it clear: a syntax error is a script-breaking error. You can't do "if the script breaks, do something" from inside the script.